# How does one remove the question mark displayed while an image is being downloaded?

Tags: javascript, image

When a user clicks on a button, images are downloaded.

While they are being downloaded Safari shows a question mark.

How can I get rid of this?

I considered the onerror event listener but this is not an error.  It simply takes time for the images to download.  It is not that the image is not at the specefied src.

The image tag is being added to the dom of the page after an ajax call.  While the image element waits for access to the actual image it shows this annoying question mark.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: i'd recommend not trying to solve non-problems.  This is the way that browser works.  Users of that browser know that.

Answer (score 3):

Hide the wrapping element until the image has fully loaded. You can hook an onload event to the image, then have it show the wrapping element when complete.

Comment: this seems like the simplest as I was already doing this for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Preload your images before you show them.

Or, have an image which is a spinner that is a placeholder while the image is being loaded.

Or, wait to show the image until it is loaded.

Comment: I can't preload because the src is not known until the user hit a button.  This button initiates an ajax call which then populates the page with the dynamic image elements.

Comment: What do you mean by spinner?

Comment: I think the 3rd option is the simplest and similar/same to Diodeus

Comment: @Hiro - Yes, the third option is similar to what Diodeus suggests. A spinner - as in, an animated `.gif` which shows an image. This image is "in front" of the image which is loading. So when the image fully loads, the spinner no longer shows. This creates the affect of movement while the user waits for their image.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the image itself to load. Create the image element and add an `onload` callback before setting the `src` property. In the callback you can add the image to the dom.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<img>`-tags from your HTML sourcecode. Load the images with Javascript as as `Image()` objects. Add onload handlers to the images. Make these onload images create the `<img>` tags and insert them into the DOM.

```
Image image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
     // insert image into your DOM 
}
image.src = 'yourImage.jpg';
```